# Android On click change text box text

Tags: android, imageview

So i have a text box and i want to do a ImageView on click and when you click it the text in the textbox will change. how can i do this?

My current code is

```
Package com.momentum.snakeEncyclopedia;


import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ballpython extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

//Variable for main image
ImageView display;

@Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.ballpython);

        // Image Views set
        display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ballpython2);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.region);
        ImageView video = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        ImageView home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);

        // Set on Click Listeners
        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        video.setOnClickListener(this);
        home.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
// set the on clicks here
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.region:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.ballpython1);
                 findViewById(R.id.other).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 findViewById(R.id.leftarrow).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 findViewById(R.id.rightarrow).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case R.id.video:
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                break;
            case R.id.home:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.ballpython2);
                findViewById(R.id.leftarrow).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.rightarrow).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.other).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your use case scenario, you can use the "onclick" attribute in the XML file. Put in the name of the method you want to call (without parentheses) and then implement that method taking in a View as the only parameter.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/ui-1.6.html
Scroll to the bottom and you will see the usage example.